# problema al insertar datos, conflicto con llave foranea

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy utilizando SQL SERVER y al momento de realizar un Insert en la tabla me sale el siguiente error.

```
Mens. 547, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 34
Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "Fk_IdPais". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "CentroMedico", tabla "dbo.Pais", column 'IdPais'.
Se terminó la instrucción.
```

el codigo fuente para la creacion de las tablas es el siguiente.

```
Create Table Pais(
Id Int Identity(1,1) Not Null,
IdPais  as Right ('CNP000' +  Cast (Id as Varchar(80)),80)  Persisted ,
Nombre_Pais Varchar(70) Not Null,
Constraint Pk_IdPais Primary Key(IdPais)
```

)

```
Create Table Pacientes(
    Id int Identity(1,1) Not Null,
    IdPaciente as Right ('PCN00000000000000'+ CAST(Id as Varchar(50)),50) Persisted,
    Nombre Varchar(50) Not Null,
    Apellido Varchar(50) Not Null,
    Domicilio Varchar(30) Not Null,
    Telefono Varchar(30) Not Null,
    Fecha_Nacimiento Date Not Null,
    IdPais Varchar(80) Not Null,
    Fecha_Registro Datetime 
    Constraint PK_Idpaciente Primary Key (Idpaciente)
    Constraint Fk_IdPais Foreign Key(IdPais) References Pais (IdPais)
    )
```

Creo que el problema es por el campo calculado en país  y lo estoy referenciando a través de una `Foreign Key` en pacientes como un campo `Varchar`, como hago para pasar ese campo calculado a `Varchar`? del mismo tamaño que el de la tabla `Pacientes`. `Alter table` me servira? alguien que me pueda colaborar. gracias.

Comment: esto es SQL Server o que gestor usas?

Comment: Utilzo Sql Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creé las tablas e inserté registros, y todo funciona bien. Asegúrate que el valor del campo `IdPais` que insertas en la tabla Pacientes sea correcto.

```
insert into pais values('China'); --Idpais = 'CNP00001'
insert into pacientes values('juan','perez','domicilio','78978','2019-01-01','CNP0001','2019-01-01')
```